# IronPdf - Signature not displaying in Signature Panel

Tags: c#, pdf, digital-signature, ironpdf

I'm attempting to create a sample PDF in IronPDF using their example, with a slight modification

```
// Step 1. Create a PDF
ChromePdfRenderer Renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
using PdfDocument doc = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Testing 2048 bit digital security</h1>");

// Step 2. Create a Signature.
// You may create a .pfx or .p12 PDF signing certificate using Adobe Acrobat Reader.
// Read: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/digital-ids.html
var Signature = new IronPdf.Signing.PdfSignature("My_Signature.pfx", "123abc!");

// Step 3. Optional signing options and a handwritten Signature graphic
Signature.SigningContact = "support@ironsoftware.com";
Signature.SigningLocation = "Chicago, USA";
Signature.SigningReason = "To show how to sign a PDF";

//Step 4. Sign the PDF with the PdfSignature. Multiple signing certificates may be used
doc.SignPdfWithDigitalSignature(Signature);

//Step 5. The PDF is not signed until saved to file, steam or byte array.
doc.SaveAs("sample.pdf");
```

The file creates and I can open the file. I can additionally see the following output. I am clearly told that there is a signature and it's valid. However, there's no actual signature showing up in the list.

Is this an error in how I'm creating the PDF? A disconnect between this and Adobe? Or something else?

[image: Signature panel]

Comment: Can you share the example signed PDF?

Comment: Well, that was the screenshot.  Did you want the actual file attached as well?

Comment: *"Did you want the actual file attached as well?"* - Yes. To analyze whether the signature is there, merely not correctly referenced, or whether it's not there at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. It has already been solved in IronPdf version [2023.6.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/2023.6.10). The `SignPdfWithDigitalSignature` method has been deprecated, please use the `Sign` method. Check the following code example for reference:

```cs
// Step 1. Create a PDF
ChromePdfRenderer Renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
PdfDocument doc = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Testing 2048 bit digital security</h1>");

// Step 2. Create a Signature.
// You may create a .pfx or .p12 PDF signing certificate using Adobe Acrobat Reader.
// Read: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/digital-ids.html
var Signature = new IronPdf.Signing.PdfSignature("My_Signature.pfx", "123abc!");

// Step 3. Optional signing options and a handwritten Signature graphic
Signature.SigningContact = "support@ironsoftware.com";
Signature.SigningLocation = "Chicago, USA";
Signature.SigningReason = "To show how to sign a PDF";

//Step 4. Sign the PDF with the PdfSignature. Multiple signing certificates may be used
doc.Sign(Signature);

//Step 5. The PDF is not signed until saved to file, steam or byte array.
doc.SaveAs("sample.pdf");
```

To learn more about digital signing with IronPdf please visit [Digitally Sign a PDF Document](https://ironpdf.com/how-to/signing/)